# How to burn iso of a program on USB?

Tags: iso, burning, matlab, usb-creator

I want to burn the iso of a program (specifically the MatLab iso) on to a USB stick with ubuntu. just to make it clear

```
what?           burn iso of program
where?          on USB stick
using which OS? Ubuntu
```

To install matlab you can burn the iso onto a dvd, but i will like to do it on my USB stick; i read somewhere that it was possible

i am NOT trying to burn the image of Ubuntu, to do that you can easily use the startup disk creator. However you cannot use it to install a iso that is not a OS

Comment: If you're goal is to use the ISO on linux, just mount the ISO file. If you want to use it on Windows, mount it on Ubuntu and copy the files to the USB. If it's not going to be a bootable USB there is no need for burning.

Comment: you can use `dd` command to dump any kind of iso or img file to a disk, assuming your USB disk is mounted at **sdb** use it like this: `sudo dd if=/path/to/iso of=/dev/sdb1`, make sure you check the mount point before issuing the command and do not overwrite your hard disk.

Comment: @Gufran thanks the command code but for some reason it was taking a reallly long time to complete the action (1hr+). How long should it take for an iso of 5.9GB? i aborted the terminal (ctrl c) and plug it in windows but says that i need to format it to use the disk

Comment: since `dd` does not show progress it might feel a long duration to you, and obviously it is also affected by the data transfer rate of your USB. I cant tell you exactly how much time should it take but on a USB 2.0 hub (~20 MB/s) it should not take that long. You can check the progress of `dd` command by USR1 sig, Initiate `dd` like this `sudo dd if=/path/to/iso of=/dev/sdb1& pid=$!` and then run `kill -USR1 $pid` this will display the progress and data transfer rate

Comment: transfer rate of 1.8MB/s, isn't that a little low?
with the an iso of 5.9GB it will take little less than an hr.
an the transfer rate is going down..

Comment: after about an hr i finished the process but still when plugged into windows it asked me to format it. how come?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ISO image is a file that contains a complete copy of a CD or DVD. You can either use this file to create a DVD or mount the file on a local drive.

On Linux, you will need to use the mount command. First make a mount point, which is just a folder. For example:

```
mkdir /media/mathworks
```

Then mount the downloaded ISO to that directory. For this example, the ISO is in the home folder under the downloads folder and the ISO is called **matlab.iso**(if you have downloaded on to the same system):

```
mount -t iso9660 -o loop ~/downloads/matlab.iso /media/mathworks
```

Now you can navigate there and run the installer as if it were a copy of the DVD, for example:

```
cd /media/mathworks  


./install
```

On Windows, this would require third-party software to create a virtual CD or DVD drive from an ISO image.

Comment: thanks
what about if i want to install MatLab on windows?
i have the iso file for both OS

Comment: If you want to mount an iso in Windows you can use poweriso amongst others.